# “WLAN API is not supported on platform earlier than Windows XP.”

Tags: visual-c++

When including `wlanapi.h` I get the following error message:

```
Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\wlanapi.h(56) : fatal error C1189:
#error :  WLAN API is not supported on platform earlier than Windows XP.
```

How can I resolve this compiler error?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have [_WIN32_WINNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx) defined as an earlier version than XP (`0x0500` or below). Define it according to the minimal platform you'd like your program to run on - find out were it's currently defined (either in the project's [compiler settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) or in the code), and change the value to, say, _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP (whose actual value is `0x0501`).